# Do limited dragons count as rare dragons for the Epic Breeding Island?

Tags: dragonvale

The in game text for this item says:

> Plus, our magical projections lead us to believe that some of the rarer dragon hybrids might come about more frequently without the distractions of a normal breeding cave.

So, for these purposes do the limited dragons like Bloom and Panlong count as "rarer dragon hybrids"?

Comment: I think it depends; some limited dragons don't seem "rare" and appear to have the same chance of appearing as any other dragon...but I don't have any numbers.

Comment: From experience, Bloom aren't rare in chance, but Panlong are; not sure if it actually counts for the island though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience I think that the Limited dragons are put onto the list as partially rare. Seing that I got a Bone & Love dragon by accident. I don't think those ones are especially rare, but accordin to some people the clover dragon was even rarer than the rainbow dragon, I'm not saying that this is true or not... So. To get to the point. I think that some limited dragons are considered as rare. But most are just cartagorized as uncommon. If this was any help to any one then I was happy to help!

Comment: @BenBrocka and I have both observed this to be the case as well.  Bloom was appeared to be an "Uncommon" or even "Common" dragon.  Sakura is proving to be "Rare", and BenBrocka said that Clover was exceedingly rare.  I have so far only received one Sakura and it was via the EBI (out of about 20 attempts), so I believe it is playing a role there.